# Remove DOM element if it contains a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code where it checks if the Name exists and if it does it deletes the span tag it's nested in.

```
<div id="box">
  <br>
  <span style="font-size: 12px">
    <a>
      <span style="color: #000000">
        <b>Name</b>
      </span>
    </a>
  </span>
```

However name can be also placed in these tags:

```
  <br>
  <span>
    <a>Name</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

How would I use jquery to check it?
I've tried:

```
$('span:contains("Name")').remove();
$('span > a > span b:contains("Name")').remove();
```

Nothing seems to work.

Edit#2: Also there are br tags I just included them. I'd like to remove them only if they're before the removed  tags.

Thanks.

Comment: "How would I do this?" isn't really a valid title. Please describe your problem in a few words

Comment: `$('span:contains("Name")').remove()` *should* work, since the documentation says `The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof`. Can you reproduce your problem in a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I would use some identifier (e.g. a class or data-* attribute) to specify the element to remove. Referring to a label for some programmatic decision could cause problems, for example if you plan to exchange those labels/have them set by an editor.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nt67p/1/ seems to be working

Comment: How do you load this content? Ajax function .load() ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` if you want to target exactly element with text "Name", not as `:contains` which will target element with text e.g "Name with some other text...":

***Set code inside .load() callback function***

```
$('#box').load('myUri', function () {
    $('#box span').has('b, a').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === "Name";
    }).remove();
});
```

Equivalent to `:contains` would be:

```
$('#box span').has('b, a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf("Name") != -1;
}).remove();
```

**UPDATED FOLLOWING COMMENT:**

```
$('#box').load('myUri', function () {
     $('#box span').has('b, a').filter(function () {
         var toRemoveSpan = $(this).text().indexOf("Name") != -1 ? true : false;
         if (toRemoveSpan && $('span').prev('br').length) {
             $(this).prev('br').remove()
         }
         return toRemoveSpan;
     }).remove();
 });
```

This will give the same than just: `$('#box').empty();`

If this is not behaviour you want, you have to be more specific in your question.

Comment: Also there are br tags I just included them. I'd like to remove them only if they're before the removed tags.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$('a:contains("Name"),b:contains("Name")').parents("span").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the edit, you need to execute teh script after the element is loaded.

You need to make use of the callback of the loading method to do it, if you are using .load() then it has a success callback where you can make call this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('div#box span a span b:not(:contains("Name"))').remove();
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/Kxwp4/)**